# MySQL - optimize query (LIMIT, OFFSET, JOIN) > 25 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sqlperformance

I want to get 100 of the 1000 most viewed lots in past auctions (randomized). I have a MySQL database, all tables using InnoDB.

Hardware: Intel i7 6700, 32 GB RAM, SSD (do not know how many IOPS).

Some informations about my my.cnf:

```
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

# mysqltuner
query_cache_type    = 1
join_buffer_size    = 256K
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 11G
```

MySQL-Tuner output:

```
>>  MySQLTuner 1.6.0 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 28G (Tables: 456)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 18

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] There is no anonymous account in all database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[--] There is 605 basic passwords in the list.

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 18d 5h 43m 18s (80M q [51.384 qps], 827K conn, TX: 539B, RX: 28B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 58% / 42%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 11.3G global + 1.1M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 11.3G (36.31% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 11.5G (36.76% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/80M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (17/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (11/827974)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 74.7% (50M cached / 67M selects)
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 650750
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (1K temp sorts / 744K sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 26% (160K on disk / 593K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (70 created / 827K connections)
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (416 open / 169K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 2% (21/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (624 immediate / 624 locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (3M used / 16M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/43.0K
[!!] Read Key buffer hit rate: 77.3% (172 cached / 39 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 11.0G/28.3G
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[OK] InnoDB Used buffer: 98.87% (712671 used/ 720852 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.77% (20288463287 hits/ 20335997890 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 733034 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64:
    Beware that open_files_limit (1024) variable
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 431)
Variables to adjust:
    query_cache_size (> 16M)
    tmp_table_size (> 32M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 32M)
    table_open_cache (> 431)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 28G) if possible.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=11)
```

I manage the random part with a randomized `OFFSET` within PHP:
`$offsetRand = rand(0, 1000-100);`
The randomized offset is then appended to the sql query.

This leads to the following query:

```
SELECT l.id FROM Auction a 
INNER JOIN Lot l ON a.id = l.auction_id 
WHERE a.startDate < "2018-11-09" 
ORDER BY l.views DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 543
```

`Explain` result of the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys                 | key                   | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,auction_startDate_idx | auction_startDate_idx | 5       | NULL               | 33864 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | NULL       | ref   | IDX_33CC6FFB57B8F0DE          | IDX_33CC6FFB57B8F0DE  | 5       | lotsearch_new.a.id |   320 |   100.00 | NULL                                                      |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Table `Auction`: 70000 rows
Table `Lot`: 27 million rows

Indices `Lot` table:

```
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| lot   |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | id          | A         |    23945704 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| lot   |          0 | UNIQ_33CC6FFB989D9B62 |            1 | slug        | A         |    23945900 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| lot   |          1 | IDX_33CC6FFB57B8F0DE  |            1 | auction_id  | A         |       74748 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| lot   |          1 | lot_visible_idx       |            1 | visible     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| lot   |          1 | lot_hammerPrice_idx   |            1 | hammerPrice | A         |       59499 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| lot   |          1 | lot_views_idx         |            1 | views       | A         |        3440 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Indices `Auction` table:

```
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| auction |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | id              | A         |       67729 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          0 | UNIQ_1159CC0FED9CD316 |            1 | md5Image_id     | A         |       57263 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          1 | IDX_1159CC0F38248176  |            1 | currency_id     | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          1 | IDX_1159CC0F47EE7BD5  |            1 | auctionhouse_id | A         |         752 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          1 | IDX_1159CC0F8BAC62AF  |            1 | city_id         | A         |         100 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          1 | auction_visible_idx   |            1 | visible         | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| auction |          1 | auction_startDate_idx |            1 | startDate       | A         |        8810 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Table `Lot`:

```
CREATE TABLE `Lot` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `auction_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `url` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `startPrice` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `endPrice` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hammerPrice` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `trained` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `classifiedByCategory` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `goldStandard` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `slug` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_33CC6FFB989D9B62` (`slug`),
 KEY `IDX_33CC6FFB57B8F0DE` (`auction_id`),
 KEY `lot_visible_idx` (`visible`),
 KEY `lot_hammerPrice_idx` (`hammerPrice`),
 KEY `lot_views_idx` (`views`),
 KEY `id` (`id`,`auction_id`,`views`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_33CC6FFB57B8F0DE` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_id`) REFERENCES `Auction` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39363610 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Table Auction:

```
CREATE TABLE `Auction` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `currency_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `auctionhouse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `startDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `endDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `url` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `priceType` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '0: Aufrufpreis | 1: Schätzpreis | 2: Limitpreis; Standard: 0',
 `identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `viewing` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `useLocalImages` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `md5Image_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `importedViaApi` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `salecode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_1159CC0FED9CD316` (`md5Image_id`),
 KEY `IDX_1159CC0F38248176` (`currency_id`),
 KEY `IDX_1159CC0F47EE7BD5` (`auctionhouse_id`),
 KEY `IDX_1159CC0F8BAC62AF` (`city_id`),
 KEY `auction_visible_idx` (`visible`),
 KEY `auction_startDate_idx` (`startDate`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_1159CC0F38248176` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `Currency` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_1159CC0F47EE7BD5` FOREIGN KEY (`auctionhouse_id`) REFERENCES `Auctionhouse` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `FK_1159CC0F8BAC62AF` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `City` (`id`),
 CONSTRAINT `FK_1159CC0FED9CD316` FOREIGN KEY (`md5Image_id`) REFERENCES `AuctionMd5Image` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116337 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

FK constraint: `Lot.auction_id` <=> `Auction.id` (only FK necessary for the to-be-optimized-query)

This query does not finish within a reasonable time (< 500ms), it runs for minutes.
If I execute `SELECT id FROM Auction WHERE startDate < :date;` the query finishes within 80ms.
If I execute `SELECT id FROM Lot ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50` the query finishes also in 20ms. So it seems that the join operation does take a long time.

So why this is so slow when combined with a join? How can I fasten up the query?

Comment: Please share details of indexing on both the tables (if any defined).

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? What are the relations your tables have? Are you indexing your PKs and FKs? This may help if you start by converting all your tables to InnoDB. You even may try to use MyRocks by Facebook instead of InnoDB. Also the most important thing is your hardware do you have an optimized hardware for I/Os. Tuning Mysql also helps especially as your table seems growing 24M rows is already a big one.

Comment: added information about hardware, mysql conf and index configuration. Do you think I need to set up an NoSQL database handling the 27 million rows? I also use `sphinxsearch` for fulltext searching within the 27 million rows...

Comment: Why are you using a left join? You need inner... unless you want the query to return NULLs.

Comment: And may be create an index on lot `(auctionid, views, id)`.

Comment: @mfuesslin  EXPLAIN for each of the queries you want us to review would be very helpful.  It will identify the ROWS for each step of the processing to be a clue where an appropriate index is NOT available.

Comment: @mfuesslin Please also post COMPLETE text report from mysqltuner.pl so we have additional valuable high level information, including table counts by engine and data sizes, RAM available, opens/limits, max connections used/available.

Comment: @mfuesslin  Do you have flexibility to compute :low_a_startdate as :date LESS 5 years to limit your range of dates to be considered?  If yes, WHERE a.startdate BETWEEN :low_a_startdate AND :date rather than your current WHERE a.start < :date MIGHT be helpful.  Show us the EXPLAIN for your new version of date selection and the OLD EXPLAIN from the simple less than date, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck added informations in my question. I would rather need to search all years for the most viewed lots. Only if not possible (performance wise) I will limit to some smaller time period.

Comment: @mfuesslin Try this out - WHERE a.startDate BETWEEN MIN(a.startDate) AND :date -  rather than your current WHERE a.startDate < :date MIGHT be helpful. Show us the EXPLAIN for your new version of date selection and the OLD EXPLAIN from the simple less than date, please. Your use of < forces a table scan that might be avoided. The EXPLAINS will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT ...
            LIMIT 1000
         ) AS x
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 100
```

The subquery will first get the 1000 "most viewed".  The outer query will pick a random 100 from the 1000.

The outer query is "fast enough" for your purposes, so we need to focus on the inner query, since it seems to require a messy JOIN between two tables?  You mentioned "most viewed", then you mentioned something about "older than :Date".  Please update your question a valid query that will find the 1000.  Then maybe we can help you optimize that.

And plese provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s).

Comment: The most viewed is calculated in my query by the `ORDER` function (ORDER BY l.views DESC). The `LIMIT 100` will get me 100 results, `OFFSET` will randomly select a starting point to retrieve my 100 most viewed within the 1000 most viewed. The date is simply something "2018-09-11" f.e.